# Nurse Scheduling with Competence Constraints

Tags: job-scheduling, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I am struggling to figure out how I can leverage Google OR Tools CP-SAT solver to find a feasible solution to the nurse scheduling problem with a slight modification: each shift is restricted to a subset of nurses who have certain competences (i.e. novice, intermediate, advanced). Competences expire after a time, meaning a nurse cannot be scheduled for a shift requiring an expired competence. However, a nurse can regain competence by working on a shift with someone who currently has that competence.

In my program, I am hoping to schedule multiple days at a time. How can I define a constraint that says a nurse with expired competence can only be scheduled for a shift on day n provided that the nurse is scheduled to regain competence on some day less than n?

Answer (score 4):

First look at the [shift_scheduling_sat.py](https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py) example. Adapting to skills restrictions should be easy.

Now, about expiration.

The first step is to mark shifts where the nurse learns the skill.

For each shifts, for each nurse, create a `bool var` if the nurse is paired with somebody who has the competence. Add the implication nurse is schedule on that shift & skilled person on the same shift -> nurse is qualified for that competence on that shift.

Now for all other shifts requiring that competence,

you know the times of each shift. For a given shift, collect all potential preceding shifts close enough (no expiration), and add nurse works on this shift implies Or(nurse acquired that shift on one compatible preceding shift -- including this one).

Comment: Thanks! I will draft an attempt at that today. The "implies" functionality of this new model sounds awesome.

Comment: `nurse works on this shift implies Or(nurse acquired that shift on one compatible preceding shift -- including this one).`

Did you mean to say `nurse acquired that competence on one compatible preceding shift`?

Comment: boolvar implies constraint is written as model.AddConstraint().OnlyEnforceIf(boolvar). Not that this is just an implication, not an equivalence.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: How might you handle the case where the instructor is also relearning the competence on a preceding line? That is, where Nurse B can’t instruct Nurse C without Nurse A teaching Nurse B first.

Comment: same idea, nurse b learned in the compatible shift before if paired with a nurse who can teach him/her. Same bool_or, recursively IMO.

Comment: I’m probably missing something here — how do I bootstrap the base case where nurses require no instructor because they already have a current (non-expired) competence? I want to schedule a nurse only if she has a current competence, or if she is paired on a preceding shift with a instructor nurse who is current in that competence during that shift.

Comment: For that nurse, change the formula to compute if the nurse has the skill to true at that beginning of the schedule

Comment: If I post my code later today could we reference that instead? I think it will be immediately clear to you what’s wrong.

Comment: Laurent -- please view my edit and let me know how I can achieve my intent. If anything is unclear about my requirements, I'd be very happy to clarify! This has been driving me crazy.

Comment: I would say: bool_or([not(paired_with_instructor), not(at_beggining), can_fly]). This will propagate if any condition is met, the pilot can fly. Then bool_or([not(can_fly), paired_with_instructor, at_beginning)] will imply that if the pilot can fly, one alternative needs to be true. Then you can add implications paired_with_instructor implies at least one instructor per skill, and so on.

Comment: @LaurentPerron this is incredibly useful code that applies to what I am working on as well. I have an additional constraint that needs to take into account weekend shifts. Any chance you can take a look at my question here as well? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69518842/nurse-scheduling-with-weekend-constraints